# Is there an easy way to get details about a csv file and how?

Tags: csv, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a csv that I would like to gather details about using Coldfusion

I have 2 columns that I would like to gather details for:
-Comapny
-Amount

The details that I would like to gather are:
-I would like to select each Distinct Company
-I would like to select how many rows there are for each Company
-I also want to Select the SUM of amount for each distinct Company

What would be the best and fastest way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069619/coldfusion-ordering-rows-according-to-a-value-in-a-txt) you know about using cfhttp to get a query object.  Your query of queries becomes

```
select company, count(company) CompanyCount, sum(amount) CompanyAmount
from YourQueryObject
group by company
```

**Edit begins here**

Since the amount is a varchar, you'll have to cast it.

```
select company, count(company) CompanyCount, sum(cast amount as decimal) CompanyAmount
from YourQueryObject
group by company
```

However, before you do that, you might want to do this:

```
 <cfset QueryAddColumn(YourQueryObject, 'IsGoodRecord', ArrayNew(1))>
 <cfloop query="YourQueryObject">
 validation code, plus set IsGoodRecord to 0 or 1
 </cfloop>
```

Then add

```
 where IsGoodRecord = 1
```

to your query of queries.

Comment: Hi Dan! When I run it, I get the following error:Query Of Queries runtime error.

 The aggregate function [SUM(expression)] cannot operate on an operand of type [VARCHAR].Is there a way to convert it to int? i do know that the values in the csv are decimal values

Comment: Hi @DanBracuk! I think I am adding the code in wrong, does the loop and set go inside of your query or does the query go inside of the loop , or does the set and loop go above the query?

Comment: Validating user input is often the first thing you do.